# Error loading local html on StageWebViewBridge

Tags: html, flash, apache-flex, air, stagewebviewbridge

I´m getting this error when I try to load a local html on StageWebViewBridge container:

> Error #2044: Unhandled ErrorEvent:. text=Load error.

code:

```
private function onDiskCacheEnd( e:StageWebviewDiskEvent ):void{
    bridge = new StageWebViewBridge( 0, 0, 1280, 720 );
    bridge.loadLocalURL('applink://index.html');
...
```

index.html is located in www folder.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Never actually tried this, but the documentation (https://code.google.com/p/stagewebviewbridge/wiki/ContentLoading) only uses a single slash.

So instead of:
'applink://index.html'

the docs use:
"applink:/index.html"

Answer (score 0):

Here StageWebView cannot refer the URL you given in loadURL(), because applink is get reference by single slash in the document. But i couldnt try with applink. StageWebViewBridge is doesn't handle ErrorEvent in their override protected addEventListener function. If you need to handle this error event you should add

```
    override public function addEventListener( type : String, listener : Function, useCapture : Boolean = false, priority : int = 0, useWeakReference : Boolean = false ) : void
    {
        switch( type )
        {
            case ErrorEvent.ERROR:
            case Event.COMPLETE:
            case LocationChangeEvent.LOCATION_CHANGING:
            case LocationChangeEvent.LOCATION_CHANGE:
            case FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN:
            case FocusEvent.FOCUS_OUT:
                _view.addEventListener( type, listener, useCapture, priority, useWeakReference );
                break;
            default:
                super.addEventListener( type, listener, useCapture, priority, useWeakReference );
                break;
        }
    }
```

and also need to remove listeners like,

```
  override public function removeEventListener( type : String, listener : Function, useCapture : Boolean = false ) : void
    {
        switch( type )
        {
            case ErrorEvent.ERROR:
            case Event.COMPLETE:
            case LocationChangeEvent.LOCATION_CHANGING:
            case LocationChangeEvent.LOCATION_CHANGE:
            case FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN:
            case FocusEvent.FOCUS_OUT:
                _view.removeEventListener( type, listener, useCapture );
                break;
            default:
                super.removeEventListener( type, listener, useCapture );
                break;
        }
    }
```

now you can handle the ErrorEvent by

```
     webView.addEventListener( ErrorEvent.ERROR, onLoadURLErrorTriggered );
```

and, you always better to give file url to load local html file like,

```
     var file : File = new File("file-path");
     webView.loadURL( file.url );
```